# OpenCL half square root

Tags: opencl

I'm developing for a GPU running OpenCL 1.2.

I'm trying to use half square root function, to calculate the square root of my half datatype.

However for all the half_square root functions, end up being a macro expansion to the standard square root function.

This results in compiler errors as none of the function overloads match the half datatype.

I'm using the following pragma in my kernel file `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp16 : enable`

Comment: You could try `half_sqrt(x)`. This guarantees a minimum of 10 bits of accuracy, but the vendor may still choose to implement it using float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`half` type support in OpenCL is only available if the `cl_khr_fp16` extension is available. It is optional and not available on all devices. An application may query the configuration information using the op-code `CL_DEVICE_HALF_FP_CONFIG` with `clGetDeviceInfo` for an OpenCL device that supports half precision floating-point. See https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_fp16.html

The exception is that if *images* are supported you can have images that contain `half` types, but all reads and writes and calculations are done in single precision `float`. The other exception is that you can use the Vector Data Load/Store functions (e.g., `vload_half`) to load and save `half` values from memory to `float` scalars and vectors. In neither case are calculations such as `sqrt` being done in `half`, just storage.

Comment: I'm using Nvidea K20 GPU. It seems like half storage is available, but not computation. Thanks for your answer.